# Modifying original data from detailView?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on iPhone and I'm using navigation.

I have list of data in RootViewController, and pass one data to detailViewController when a cell is clicked. Like this,

```
detailViewController.message = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And I want to modify the content of 'message' in detailViewController. Is that possible?

I've tried that, but I get an error that it's immutable object. How can I do that? Somebody give me a hint. Thanks ;)

Added ------------------------------------------------

Ok. I'll specify the question.

in detailViewController, the message is decleared NSMutableDictionary* type.

and used like this.

```
NSMutableString *str = [m_message objectForKey:KEY_CONTENT];
[str appendFormat:@"appended!"];
```

And I've got this message.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendFormat:'

Can't I just modify it's content like modifying data in c++ using pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be best to use a delegate pattern for this. Create a DetailViewControllerDelegate protocol that informs its delegate of a changed message. Something along the lines of:

```
-(void)detailViewController:(DetailViewController *)controller didChangeMessage:(NSString *)message;
```

You could also directly manipulate the object by using a mutable one (NSMutableString, NSMutableArray etc.), but using a delegate improves reusability and decouples your classes.

**EDIT:**

The fact that your dictionary is mutable doesn't mean the object inside it are mutable as well. Your string `str` is probably immutable. Since NSMutableString is a subclass of NSString, the assignment will work though. You should make sure that you put a mutable string in the dictionary, or use the mutableCopy method of NSString to get a mutable copy of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I just added some detail about question. Of course your answer is helpful but I want to see another way.

Comment: See my last edit for more info on the mutable/immutable problem.

Comment: / Thanks. Maybe this was the problem! I'll try to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of object you are passing. Immutable means that you cant alter the object. If you for exaple use NSArray, you have to switch to NSMutableArray instead. The same for string or dictionary.

Comment: I used MutableDictionary & MutableString. Still get immutable error. Can you point what I did wrong? I modified the question little bit. Please read & currect me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i think i figured it out. The documentation for appendFormat says that appendFormat is for appending objects, just like when you use stringWithFormat.

The documentation states that:

> The appended string is formed using
>   NSString's stringWithFormat: method
>   with the arguments listed.

You should use appendString to get the result you want.